# Is it required to ask for permission for push notifications?

Tags: typescript, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4

I've watched 2 different tutorials for creating push notifications in firebase.  One asks for permission using the firebaseNative plugin and the FCM tutorial does not ask for permissions.  Is there a specific use case in which you'd use either one of these plugins for creating push notifications in firebase?

Here is the first tutorial using ionic-native

```
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase/ngx';

  if (this.platform.is('android')) {
    token = await this.firebaseNative.getToken()
  } 

  if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    token = await this.firebaseNative.getToken();
    await this.firebaseNative.grantPermission();
  } 

  return this.saveTokenToFirestore(token)
}
```

and the second using fcm.

```
    this.plt.ready()
      .then(() => {
        this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
          if (data.wasTapped) {
          } else {
          };
        });

        this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
          // backend.registerToken(token);
        });
      })
  }
  getToken() {
    this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
      // backend.registerToken(token);
    });
  }
```

If creating a chat app which would be best and what's the difference between the two?

Comment: I am using ionic 4 with fcm and it works really nice. It's easy to setup fcm notification in the application. You can trigger notifications using server-side script e.g. PHP

Comment: Does it prompt a user if they consent to using push notification?